# Movie about an old woman telling her life story to a film crew

Tags: millennium-actress

Way back in 2003-4 my girlfriend at the time was watching an anime with her family.

The things I remember about it are that it kind of gave me a Titanic vibe with the lady re-telling her life story. However, when she told her stories, it transported the film crew (metaphorically?) into the past to record her life story.

I'd love to watch this film again, this time with my wife.

Comment: Also sounds like *Atonement* except there was no explicit film crew.

Answer (score 8):

You are referring to the 2001 film "[Millennium Actress](http://letterboxd.com/film/millennium-actress/)" (Sennen Joyû) by director Satoshi Kon.

> A movie studio is being torn down. TV interviewer Genya Tachibana has tracked down its most famous star, Chiyoko Fujiwara, who has been a recluse since she left acting some 30 years ago. Tachibana delivers a key to her, and it causes her to reflect on her career; as she's telling the story, Tachibana and his long-suffering cameraman are drawn in.

[image]